# Buttons and TabPane not picking up OnMouseMove event applied to its Parent

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, mouseevent

I'm currently programming an inventory system, which involves clicking to 'attach' an item to your mouse which can then be placed somewhere else.

The event which keeps track of this:

```
getMainUI().setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
            if (getStoredItem() != null){
                getStoredItem().getImage().setLayoutY( e.getSceneY() + 30);
                getStoredItem().getImage().setLayoutX( e.getSceneX() - 30);
            }
        });
```

My project structure is a StackPane as the scene root, with a BorderPane (mainUI) and normal Pane (overLay) added as children. The stored item's image follows the mouse as expected unless the mouse enters either any Button/ToggleButton in the Scene, or the right area of the BorderPane, which is a TabPane containing the inventory.

Normally I would expect there to be an element on top absorbing the event, but the only node above the UI is the overLay which has its pickBounds set to false to allow the user to click the UI. Pretty much at a loss here.

Comment: Did you try adding this handler as a filter?

Comment: Thanks @Jai that did the trick - such a simple thing can't believe I forgot about filters!

Comment: No problem. As weird as it gets, sometimes some controls do consume even mouse move events. So probably those buttons and tabs are consuming them for some reasons. Also check that you didn't break those buttons and tabs when you do filter (though it shouldn't since you didn't consume the event).